# (xlib) create my own properties for windowmanagers

Tags: c, linux, x11, xlib

Can i create my own properties with:

```
XChangeProperty(display, w, property, type, format, mode, data, nelements)
```

or can i only use the properties shown in 
standards.freedesktop.org?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create any property you want.

Just do `XInternAtom` with your unique atom name, and you have a `property` of your own. Same for `type`.

Comment: However, I advise you to have some common prefix convention for your atoms, e.g. start all their names with `_DERSAFT` or something similar).